# how to update the dataset/database daily (web scraping/ data flow)?

Tags: python, database, screen-scraping

I have managed to scrape a sports website with python & bs4 and created a dataset with all matches. The league is ongoing so every day there are newer matches. I'm still a beginner so I'm not so sure how to approach some problems I face. I want to use the match history to experiment with a prediction model but I'm not sure how to deal with the data flow.

So far I just have a csv and let's say the dataset has date, winner, loser, winner_elo, loser_elo among others. What I'm thinking I want to do is:

a) Create a database with the existing dataset (??) (Any direction is appreciated how to approach it)

b) Scrape new matches (I have a script for that)

c) Add new matches to the database (??)

d) Create a new "table" (?) with player name, date of last match, wins, losses, elo and some other player specific stats. I'm not sure how to approach this so I can get the latest entry from my dataset/database so for every player their stats are up to date.

e) In the future I want everything to be on a website I'll make and the whole process to be automated i.e. do the scraping once a day or more, update everything, do some calculations and then to be able to show the results on my site.

As I said I'm a beginner and I'm not asking for a specific code or anything like that. More like how to approach it, or how somebody more experienced would deal with it. Any direction is appreciated